# Read text file and save it in more than one matrix based on colomn Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am able to read a text file and I am able to read it line by line or all of it. But I need to put some columns in vectors.
As example if this is the whole file:

```
1000011112222
2000011112222
3000011112222
4000011112222
5000011112222
```

I need to read the first number in each row(first column which is 1 2 3 4 5 )and but it in a vector. Then I need to read from the second to the  fifth column and put them in a mtrix and from the sixth till the 8th in another matrix and so on. Any easy idea to do that?? Note: The number of columns needed is much bigger than this example(not 4 but 896 column in each matrix)

My code:

```
fid=fopen(filename, 'txt'); 
 tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline) 
  vnum = sscanf(tline);
  fnum=sscanf(tline, 'f %d %d %d');
  tline = fgetl(fid);
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Setup #1 (As listed in the sample data)**

This could be one approach based on [`fileread`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileread.html) that reads in a text file as a string data -

```
%// Read in data as a char array
char_data = fileread(file_name)

%// Convert it to a properly formatted char array with `char()` 
%// and then to a numeric array with "- '0'"
num_data = char(strsplit(char_data).') - '0'  %//'

%// Finally, separate out columns as per the set requirements
var1 = num_data(:,1)
var2 = num_data(:,2:5)
var3 = num_data(:,6:8)
```

Code run -

```
var1 =
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
var2 =
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
var3 =
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
```

---

**Setup #2**

Based on OP's comments posted below, if you have the text file setup like so -

```
0.0000000e+00 2.3000000e+01 2.1660000e+01 2.0840000e+01 ....
0.2000000e+00 2.3500000e+01 2.1660000e+01 2.0840000e+01 ....
0.3000000e+00 2.3600000e+01 2.1660000e+01 2.0840000e+01 ....
```

you can read in the data with [`importdata`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) as a cell array, split the data based on the column spacings and then collect specific columns off it as done in the previous approach. This is implemented below -

```
%// Read in data into a cell array of strings;
%// Trim whitespaces around it, should there be any
cell_data = strtrim(importdata(file_name,''))

%// Separate out columns within each cell of the cell array
cellsep_data = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x),cell_data,'Uni',0)

%// Concatenate data from all cells into a "single-level" cell array
cellsep_data1 = vertcat(cellsep_data{:})

%// Convert to numeric array
num_data = str2double(cellsep_data1)

%// Finally, separate out columns as per th set requirements
var1 = num_data(:,1)
var2 = num_data(:,2:5)
var3 = num_data(:,6:8)
```

Comment: Thanks @Divakar .. my main problem now is that each number contains more than one char, this is a sample of the data I have "0.0000000e+00   2.3000000e+01   2.1660000e+01   2.0840000e+01 " any solution for this problem? Many thanks

Comment: @SMH Not sure that I got you there. So, you have ""0.0000000e+00 2.3000000e+01 2.1660000e+01 2.0840000e+01" for example in one line of the text file? Could you edit your question with a closer representative of your actual data?

Comment: for example, instead of  having 1000011112222 as a row .. the row is like that:  0.0000000e+00   2.3000000e+01   2.1660000e+01   2.0840000e+01   2.0410000e+01   1.9940000e+01   1.9440000e+01   1.9030000e+01   1.9190000e+01   2.1500000e+01   2.2250000e+01   2.5000000e+01   2.8310000e+01

Comment: It gave me an error "Error using vertcat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent." I had a look on the cell value and I found that there is an extra empty cell at the beginning of each row

Comment: @SMH Trim them with `cell_data = strtrim(importdata(file_name,''))`?